# Returning Error Message from Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, postman

I have a Web API controller method...

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/Api/Tag/GetTagTaskMappings")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetTagTaskMappings()
    {
        try
        {
            var tagTaskMappings = _tagRepository.GetTagTaskMappings();

            if (tagTaskMappings == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(tagTaskMappings);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

I am using Postman to debug the method. 
I am testing the Web API in 2 scenarios...

1. Running in Visual Studio (IIS Express)
2. Running on IIS Manager on a remote server

Using Postman I get the desired results from scenario **1** test...

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "No Tag/Task Relationship found",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)"
}
```

However, for scenario **2** test, I only get this back from Postman...

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred."
}
```

Any idea why I am not getting the ExceptionMessage? Am I error handling correctly?

The only difference I see in Postman is scenario 1 has one extra header...

```
X-SourceFiles →=?UTF-8?B?XFxTVlB
```

Comment: Probably a Release build running on your IIS. Looks like a good default configuration. Typically you don't want to expose stacktraces to callers in production, as it reveals things about your program structure.

Comment: Tried publishing in Debug but no change. What settings on Visual Studio effect this?